# Dice query only returning with a specific fields condition

Tags: sql, database, psql, olap

We're doing a dice olap query that gets a certain production company's total revenue of a specific year on the schema below:
[image]

Using this query:

```
SELECT PC.name, RC.year, SUM(revenue) as total_revenue
FROM movies_reception_facts MR
JOIN ref_calendar RC ON MR.release_date_key = RC.date_key
JOIN pc_groups PG ON MR.pc_group_key = PG.pc_group_key
JOIN movies_pc MP ON PG.pc_group_key = MP.pc_group_key
JOIN production_companies PC ON MP.pc_id = PC.pc_id
WHERE PC.pc_id IN(
    SELECT pc_id
    FROM production_companies
    WHERE name = 'Disney') AND 
    RC.date_key IN(
        SELECT RC.date_key
        FROM ref_calendar
        WHERE RC.year = 2014
        )
GROUP BY (PC.name, RC.year)
```

The problem is that, it's only returning results when the year is set to 2014: `WHERE RC.year = 2014`. Any other value would return an empty row.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this fixes your problem, but that subquery is problematic.  First, if you did use a subquery, it would be:

```
RC.date_key IN(
    SELECT RC2.date_key
    FROM ref_calendar RC2
    WHERE RC2.year = 2014
    )
```

But a subquery is not necessary.  You can just replace the logic with:

```
RC.year = 2014
```

Then putting this condition in the `IN` clause is silly.  It should be a filter in the outer `where`.  And since the tables are already joined in, I think you just want:

```
WHERE pc.name = 'Disney' AND 
      RC.year = 2014
```

That said, I'm not sure if this fixes your problem of no data being returned for other years.

Comment: Thanks for the input, but the original problem still persists.